# Imported class populating properties from global variables

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I have a class property that I want to populate at runtime, but I don't want to pass the value. What I am doing right now is:

weird_class.py

```
class WeirdClass:
    prop = NotImplementedError
```

runtime_file.py

```
from weird_class import WeirdClass
PROP = 'somevalue'

class WeirdClassChild(WeirdClass):
    prop = PROP
```

This works, but whenever I create a `WeirdClassChild`, I have to set the `prop` value, which is irritating.

What I would like is for `WeirdClassChild` to automatically pick up the PROP global variable without me specifically telling it to.

I would like to do something like:

```
class WeirdClass:
    prop = __global_namespace__.PROP
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Do you want prop to be a property of the class or the instance?  In the first example it is a class attribute, in the second it is an instance attribute.

Comment: @shx2 edited for clarity - I prefer it to be a class property. But I'll take it either way.

Comment: To be clear, so you have several files in which you define subclasses, and each of them already defines some value in a global variable, and you want the subclasses to automatically pick up that value, correct?

Comment: @shx2 That is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Logister Why are you trying so hard to save one line of code? It would help to know more about where PROP comes from. Are there really many props and you create many child classes, and therefore this would make your code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: Do you want WierdClassChild to have different values for prop if PROP is changed globally between creating instances?

Comment: @Harvey - (1) Yes. I have multiple equivalents of `runtime_file.py`. Each `runtime_file.py` has 10+ inheritors of `WeirdClass`. I don't want to do prop assignments every time. (2) Each `runtime_file.py` has a single PROP value that never changes, but if it were changed, I wouldn't want the classes to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inspect`ion to determine the context from which your class is instantiated:

```
# class definition
import inspect
class Weird:
    def __init__(self):
        caller_frame = inspect.stack()[1]
        caller_module = caller_frame[0]
        self.prop = caller_module.f_globals['PROP']

# instantiation
PROP = 555
x = Weird()
print(x.prop)
=> 555
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but if you have a good reason to do this...

Comment: Would you need to walk up the stack if for example the class being instantiated is a subclass of a subclass and all in different files?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use metaclasses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

PROP = "only for subclasses"


class _WierdMeta(type):
    # Not sure if you should use __init__ or __new__
    # Use one or the other.

    # `cls` is an instance of the class type that _WierdMeta creates
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if bases:
            cls.prop = PROP
        super().__init__(name, bases, dct)

    # `cls` is _WierdMeta  
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        class_type = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        if bases:
            class_type.prop = PROP
        # this return value will be the `cls` passed to __init__ above
        return class_type

class WierdBase(metaclass=_WierdMeta):
    """Base class."""
    prop = "base"


class WierdChild(WierdBase):
    pass


wb = WierdBase()
wc = WierdChild()
print(wb.prop)  # print('base') 
print(wc.prop)  # print('only for subclasses')
```

It appears that as of Python 3.6, you can do it using [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__).

```
class WierdBase():
    """Base class."""
    prop = "base"

    # I'm not 100% on the args here...
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        # ... or here.
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if cls is not WierdBase:
            cls.prop = PROP
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question... With this, the global value must already be defined when defining the metaclass.

Comment: PROP could come from an import of a global config object. PROP is not looked up until a subclass is created.

Comment: right, but PROP is looked up in the globals namespace of the metaclass, so all subclasses get the same value of PROP.

Comment: I just read the comments on the question, and I see what you mean. I don't think we can help further without more information about the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment of how you use this, why not add another base class?

```py
from weird_class import WeirdClass
PROP = 'somevalue'

class WeirdClassChildBase(WeirdClass):
    prop = PROP

class WeirdClassChild_1(WeirdClassChildBase):
    pass

class WeirdClassChild_2(WeirdClassChildBase):
    pass

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split this into three files and follow the approach explained here: https://instructobit.com/tutorial/108/How-to-share-global-variables-between-files-in-Python :

- `globals.py` - here you initialize the value of the PROP
- `weird_class.py` - here you should import the globals.py and use the PROP value
- `start.py` - here you can test the weird class, but before importing its module you should import `globals.py` and call some intialization method

The `globals.py` file will agregate all the global default values.  Assuming in a `start.py` script first you should import globals and initialize it.

```py
    import globals
    globals.initialize()
    from weird_class import WeirdClass

    c = WeirdClass()
    print(c.prop)
```

In your weird_class file you can access the variable from `globals.py` provided you have imported it:

```py
    import globals
    class WeirdClass:
        prop = globals.PROP
```

and finally the `globals.py` can look like:

```py
    def initialize():
        global PROP
        PROP = "my global value"
```

The key part here is to declare `global PROP` before setting an initial value. The `global` keyword will make the variable `global` in the module `globals`.

Having global variables, constants and all magic values in a single, central place scoped with the module is often an advantage.